# define query parameter before using it as source for a report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have

1. a view **VIEW1** with parameter [YEAR] (when I open thin view access asks me for the YEAR).

   select a, b, c from tab where y=[YEAR]
2. a view **VIEW2**

   select a, b from VIEW1
3. a report **REPORT1** using VIEW2 as source
4. a form **FORM1** with a field YEAR

Scenario:

- open the form
- enter value YEAR
- press PRINT
- report will automatically take the value from the field and pass as parameter to the data source VIEW2
- open preview for the year

Is it possible to manage this scenario via VBA?

Please note I know the way:

```
select a, b, c from tab where y=[Form1]![YEAR]
```

Problem is I would like to use VIEW1 as low level datasource from other forms and for other reports.

**UPDATE:** What I need is:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Anlage1_ken3")
  qdf.Parameters("[PARAM_YEAR]") = 2016
  qdf.Parameters("[PARAM_FIRMA]") = 1
  Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
  Me.RecordSource = rst 'I have an exception here
End Sub
```

Does anybody know a way to use this recordset as report's RecordSource ?

Answer (score 0):

Use your View1 as parameter query - something like this.

```
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("View1")

   qdf.Parameters("[Year]") =2017
   Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

See this link for a method to use the recordset in the report http://access.mvps.org/access/reports/rpt0014.htm

Apparently you can by doing this

```
Set Me.Recordset = qdf.OpenRecordset()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That looks  what I need. Then I should define rst as report source? Right? In what Report's Event handler should I place this code?

Comment: Thanks. Everything is clear but it does not solve my task with parameters. It is not allowed to set Resultset as record source. To be more accurate: it is only allowed in ADP projects.

Comment: Try the other method I've just added.